# Warning: move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, loops

i m back again still learning for multiple upload. Ok i got a situation in here. And i got 2 warning :

> Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in F:\wamp\www\dki\1\entry_fotos.php on line 32
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in F:\wamp\www\dki\1\entry_fotos.php on line 45

and  this is the code

```
   $ne_photo_images = $_FILES['ne_photo_image']['name'];
   $fe_photo_images = $_FILES['fe_photo_image']['name'];
   $tmp_file = $_FILES['ne_photo_image']['tmp_name'];
   $tmp_file1 = $_FILES['fe_photo_image']['tmp_name'];

      if(!is_array($ne_photo_images)) {
         $ne_photo_images = array();

    }

  if(!is_array($tmp_file)) {
        $tmp_file = array();
     }
       if(! move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, 'image/' . $ne_photo_images))

 if(!is_array($fe_photo_images)) {
        $fe_photo_images = array();
    }
 if(!is_array($tmp_file1)) {
        $tmp_file1 = array();
    }
    if(! move_uploaded_file($tmp_file1, 'image/' . $fe_photo_images))
```

and i got this query code from the my question feedback before

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO photo(`photo_id`, `ne_photo_image`, `fe_photo_image`, `hop_id`,    `title`) VALUES";
   for($i = 0, $l = sizeof($titles) ; $i < $l ; $i++)
   {
      //adding row datas
      $sql .= " (null, 
                 '".$ne_photo_images [$i]."', 
                 '".$fe_photo_images [$i]."', 
                 '".$hopid."', 
                 '".$titles[$i]."')";
      if($i < $l - 1)
         $sql .= ",";
   }

   if(mysql_query($sql))
   {         
   }
```

and this is my form :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table border="0"cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Hop Name :<?echo "$data[hop_name]"?>
                <input type='hidden' name='photo_hop_id' value='<?echo"$data[hop_id]"?>'>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <table border="0"cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "100%">
    <tr>
                <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "50%"> 
                    Near End Site Name : <?echo "$data[ne_site_name]"?>
                        </br>
                    Near End Site Id : <?echo "$data[ne_site_code]"?>
                </td>
                <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "50%"> 
                    Far End Site Name : <?echo "$data[fe_site_name]"?>
                        </br>
                    Far End Site Id : <?echo "$data[fe_site_code]"?>
                </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
                <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "50%"> 
                    <?  $pm1= mysql_query("SELECT photo_name FROM photo_name WHERE photo_name_id = 1");
                        $dpm1 = mysql_fetch_array ($pm1);echo"$dpm1[0]"?> 
                    <input type='hidden' name='photo_name_id[]' value='<?echo"$dpm1[0]"?>'> :  
                    <input type="file" name="ne_photo_image[]">
                </td>
                <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "50%"> 
                    <?echo "$dpm1[0]"?> : <input type="file" name="fe_photo_image[]">
                </td>
    </tr>   
    
</table>

    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="tambah" />
</form>
```

and i hope this is easier to spot. Many thanks for the help

Comment: echoing var_dump($ne_photo_images);
var_dump($fe_photo_images); with the result before execute :array (size=0)
  empty

array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: echoing var_dump($ne_photo_images); var_dump($fe_photo_images); with the result : array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Lighthouse.jpg' (length=14)

Comment: now i can finish it, maybe this can make a great tutors for the newbie

Answer (score 0):

This is causing your problems...

```
if(!is_array($ne_photo_images)) { $ne_photo_images = array(); }
if(!is_array($tmp_file)) { $tmp_file = array(); }
```

if your $ne_photo_images is not an array you change it to an empty array but you, the same is true for $tmp_file. Then you give $tmp_file as paramter to move_uploaded_file and also the $ne_photo_images, which only move a single file. Not an array of files

`enter code here`move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, 'image/' . $ne_photo_images))

You should do something like this

```
$ne_photo_images[] = $_FILES['ne_photo_image']['name'];
$ne_photo_images[] = $_FILES['fe_photo_image']['name'];
$tmp_file[] = $_FILES['ne_photo_image']['tmp_name'];
$tmp_file[] = $_FILES['fe_photo_image']['tmp_name'];
```

and then do something like

```
$allGood = true;
for($i = 0; $i < count($ne_photo_images); $i++)
{
  if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp_file[$i], 'image/' . $ne_photo_images[$i]))
  {
    $allGood = false;
  }
}

if (!$allGood) { die("Not all files where moved."); }
```

**More general solution**

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file)
{
  if (move_uploaded_files($file['tmp_name'], 'image/' . $file['name']))
  {
    // also insert the file into the database here

  }
}
```

Comment: and how if do that with two move uploaded_file, should i do twice?

Comment: You don't have to do it twice. The loop already takes care of all the files you put into the arrays. You look over all the files you have uploaded and move them all

Comment: i got this : Not all files where moved. i m really confuse

Comment: how many files are you trying to upload

Comment: 21 for ne image, 21 for fe image total 42 files

Comment: var_dump the files in $_FILES to the screen to see the array structure and see how you can add all the files in the $_FILES array into the two given arrays $ne_photo_images then upload them while looping the variable

Comment: befor i execute the output : array (size=0)
  empty , and after i execute the output : nothing (only the warning show up)

Answer (score 0):

this the the final code

```
    $hopid = $_POST['photo_hop_id'];
$titles = $_POST['photo_name_id'];

$ne_photo_images = $_FILES[ne_photo_image][name];
$fe_photo_images = $_FILES[fe_photo_image][name];

while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES['ne_photo_image']['name']))
    {
        if(!empty($value))
        {
            $filename = $value;
                $filename=str_replace(" ","_",$filename);// Add _ inplace of blank space in file name, you can remove this line

                $add = "image/$filename";
                   //echo $_FILES['images']['type'][$key];
             // echo "<br>";
                copy($_FILES['ne_photo_image']['tmp_name'][$key], $add);
                chmod("$add",0777);


        }
    }
         while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES['fe_photo_image']['name']))
    {
        if(!empty($value))
        {
            $filename = $value;
                $filename=str_replace(" ","_",$filename);// Add _ inplace of blank space in file name, you can remove this line

                $add = "image/$filename";
                   //echo $_FILES['images']['type'][$key];
             // echo "<br>";
                copy($_FILES['fe_photo_image']['tmp_name'][$key], $add);
                chmod("$add",0777);


        }
    }

              $sql = "INSERT INTO photo(`photo_id`, `ne_photo_image`, `fe_photo_image`, `hop_id`,    `title`) VALUES";
   for($i = 0, $l = sizeof($titles) ; $i < $l ; $i++)
   {
      //adding row datas
      $sql .= " (null, 
                 '".$ne_photo_images [$i]."', 
                 '".$fe_photo_images [$i]."', 
                 '".$hopid."', 
                 '".$titles[$i]."')";
      if($i < $l - 1)
         $sql .= ",";
   }

   if(mysql_query($sql))
   {         
   }

   else
```